# Column which contains NULL as value is not getting audit in audit table. I am using AFTER update trigger

Tags: mysql

```
BEGIN
IF 
    NEW.id <> OLD.id OR 
    NEW.customerId <> OLD.customerId OR 

  THEN BEGIN
     INSERT INTO customerDocuments_audit
(
id,customerId,auditActionDate,auditAction)values(NEW.id,NEW.customerId, NOW(),'update'
);
     END; END IF;
END$$
```

If I try to update a column which contains NUll value. A column is getting updated but it is not inserting any value in an audit table.

Comment: Thanks for editing. Can you please guide how to ask a question in a proper way and format.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and also [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifically check for `NULL` values as using a `NULL` value in a regular logical operation will always return a `false` result. Change your `IF` statement to this:

```
IF 
    NEW.id <> OLD.id OR 
    NEW.id IS NULL AND OLD.id IS NOT NULL OR
    NEW.id IS NOT NULL AND OLD.id IS NULL OR
    NEW.customerId <> OLD.customerId OR 
    NEW.customerId IS NULL AND OLD.customerId IS NOT NULL OR
    NEW.customerId IS NOT NULL AND OLD.customerId IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks!!! nick. It is working.  One more help. May you please how can I optimize it. Means Instead of applying the condition to each column can we apply it to a particular row.

Comment: @ShashikantKrishna you need to check individual columns because if you only check for `NULL` on a row by row basis you can't tell the difference between updating a `NULL` value to a `NULL` value and updating a `NULL` value to non-null and a non-null value to `NULL` since both cases have the same number of `NULL` values in the old and new rows.

Comment: In your solution, I got one problem. If zero row is affected. Still, it is inserting in an audit table.

Comment: @ShashikantKrishna you would need to check that all values are different to check for that.

Answer (score 0):

select a.name 
into v_newName
from Detail a
if 
v_newName is not null
Update
set a.name = v_newName
else
Update
set a.name = value

end if